# How to rename uploaded file using form API and Drupal managed_file field

Tags: 7, forms

I make a Drupal Form using FAPI (Drupal 7)
in this form I used managed_file field

```
$form['image_fid'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
);
```

I want to rename the uploaded file (make the filename = filename+date)

How can I make something like that

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know about file status, file_save & file_usage_add.

In your submit callback:

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['image_fid']);
$file->filename = 'somefilename';
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
file_usage_add($file, 'yourmodule', 'foo', 1);
```

More info at the [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file).

Comment: It does not rename the file just change filename in database but I need to change it in hard disk and save the new uri in database

Comment: See $file->uri instead of filename. Haven't got a system to confirm atm.

Comment: thanks, but it does not rename the file

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to rename file is using https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths module .

> The File (Field) Paths module extends the default functionality of
>   Drupal's core File module, Image module and many other File upload
>   modules, by adding the ability to use entity based tokens in
>   destination paths and file names.
>
> In simple terms, File (Field) Paths allows you to automatically sort
>   and rename your uploaded files using token based replacement patterns
>   to maintain a nice clean filesystem.

also you can rename it programmatically with  [hook_file_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_insert/7)

something like

```
function hook_file_insert($file)
{
    $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
    if (in_array(mb_strtolower($parts['extension']), array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'tif', 'flv', 'pdf'))) {
        $uri = 'public://' . 'dsfr_' . $file->uid . '_' . $file->timestamp . '.' . $parts['extension'];
        $file = file_move($file, $uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rename file on upload context through validator functions

here is the edited code

```
$form['image_fid'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#upload_validators'=>  array('file_validate_name' => array()),
);

function file_validate_name(stdClass $file) {
  $errors = array();

  //generate file name 
  $new_filename = convert_filename_to_filename_date($file->filename);


  $file->filename = $new_filename;

  //changing file location 
  $destination_dir = "public://file_location/";

  //check if file exists. if exists rename it append incremental number  until the filename is unique

  $file->destination = file_destination($destination_dir.$file->filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

  // If file_destination() returns FALSE then $replace == FILE_EXISTS_ERROR and
  // there's an existing file so we need to bail.
  if ($file->destination === FALSE) {
    $errors[] = t('The file %source could not be uploaded because a file by that name already exists in the destination %directory.',
    array('%source' => $file->source, '%directory' => $destination_dir));
  }

  return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days but this seems to be working for what I wanted to do:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_move/7