# Replace the file with same name

Tags: files

With reference to [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41653/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-using-form-api-and-drupal-managed-file-field/129190) for the validation function in managed_file field, but i am facing an issue with file_desitination()

```
$file->destination = file_destination($destination_dir.$file->filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

I want to replace the file with same name, entry is not been saved in file_managed table.

Code

```
    $form['image_fid'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#upload_validators'=>  array('file_validate_name' => array()),
    );

    function file_validate_name(stdClass $file) {
    $errors = array();

    //generate file name 
    $new_filename = convert_filename_to_filename_date($file->filename);


    $file->filename = $new_filename;

    //changing file location 
    $destination_dir = "public://file_location/";

    //check if file exists. if exists rename it append incremental number  until the filename is unique

    $file->destination = file_destination($destination_dir.$file->filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

    // If file_destination() returns FALSE then $replace == FILE_EXISTS_ERROR and
    // there's an existing file so we need to bail.
    if ($file->destination === FALSE) {
    $errors[] = t('The file %source could not be uploaded because a file by that name already exists in the destination %directory.',
    array('%source' => $file->source, '%directory' => $destination_dir));
    }

    return $errors;
    }
```

Comment: it will be easy to solve the issue if you update your question by adding the code you have tried for this.

Comment: Issue exist only when you try to update the uploaded image, file_managed table have filename field as unique field.Hence while updating the a new image with same name throw an error.