# Rename files on nodes

Tags: forms

I have a content type called project, and also have a filefield there. I am supposed to allow users to rename the file. For this purpose, I've tried implementing `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` and using `$form['group_file'] = array('#type' => 'fieldset', '#title' => 'Foo');` just to test, but nothing changed. Should it not fail, I will also place a button to rename the file. Below is my code. What am I missing or doing wrong? My fieldset is called group_file (at least that's what devel tells me)

```
function unsw_form_project_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['group_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Rename'),
  );
}
```

Here is the screenshot from content type settings

[image: content type settings]

Comment: Since Drupal already uploaded the file to the temp directory as soon as the user chose which file to upload, I don't believe you can rename the file during the form fillout process. You will most likely have to add some hooks to the submit handling of your form to rename the file and URI after form submission. See this post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41653/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-using-form-api-and-drupal-managed-file-field?rq=1 hope this helps

Comment: I'm not trying to rename at upload. I want to rename it later.

Comment: Can you add the code you have for the submit process? Somewhere you have to call the file system for renaming the filename/uri... just to clarify - are you asking how to change the file name after, or how to get the file rename field to show up on your content type??

Comment: in order to avoid duplicate file names in the system, the form would have to be resubmitted and validated - during that process if multiple similar names are found, you will end up with a changed file name anyways. For example if a house.jpg file already exists, and someone renames a file to house.jpg and resubmits, it will end up as house0.jpg or similar. Why do you need to allow people to change the name?

Comment: @Geoff client requirement. Should I tell them that this request makes no sense?

Comment: it really doesn't, because the system will override it to avoid file name duplicates - if you bypass the system, the write will occasionally fail because a file by that name already exists. Depending on the end purpose there may be other options that accomplish the same UI goal (customised auto file naming, user folders, fieldsets with file descriptors, etc)

Comment: I disagree with @Geoff. If client requires, you CAN modify Drupal's default behavior of duplicating the files and adding a 0 to it. I've done it many times. You can for example, check if the file name they are trying to rename it to exists already, then stop the submit process and issue an error. The key is to set up your form validation or submit handlers to do this processing. Kartagis, if you can add your submit handler code, I can offer some suggestions on how to do it.